# Component written as a class not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React component does not render, and I am unsure why. When I wrote my component as a function, it rendered fine, but when I converted it to a class (and I need it as a class so I can properly fetch .json data), the page returns blank. I am not sure where I messed up here.

**Landing.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Navigation from "components/Navigation";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

class Landing extends Component {
    state = {
        categories: []
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const url = "/api/site/categories";
            const options = {
                method: "GET",
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            };
            const response = await fetch(url, options);
            const categories = await response.json();
            this.setState({
                categories
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Navigation />
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    {this.state.categories.map(category => (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Box bgcolor="primary.main" color="primary.contrastText" p={2}>
                            <span>{category.title}</span>
                        </Box>
                    </Grid>
                ))}               
                </Grid>
            </Container>            
        );
    }
}

export default Landing;
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Landing from "components/Landing";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <Landing />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you check for errors in the console?

Comment: You're confident that `const categories = await response.json();` is an array?

Comment: Just checked console (forgot I can do that), and yeah there's an error but I have no idea what it refers to. Gonna have to make another question, lol.

Comment: `Gonna have to make another question,` You can edit your question to add the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think is is that async componentDidMount() doesn't resolve the promise from the fetch call. Try changing it to .then() instead of await.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Navigation from "components/Navigation";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

class Landing extends Component {
    state = {
        categories: []
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        try {
            const url = "/api/site/categories";
            const options = {
                method: "GET",
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            };
            fetch(url, options).then((response)=>{
            return response.json()}).then((json)=>{this.setState({categories: json});
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
render(){
          return (
            <Container>
                <Navigation />
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    {this.state.categories.map(category => (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Box bgcolor="primary.main" color="primary.contrastText" p={2}>
                            <span>{category.title}</span>
                        </Box>
                    </Grid>
                ))}               
                </Grid>
            </Container>            
        );
    }
}
export default Landing;
```

You can do the same thing with a functional component.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Navigation from "components/Navigation";
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const Landing = ()=> Component {
   const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
       useEffect(()=>{  
        try {
            const url = "/api/site/categories";
            const options = {
                method: "GET",
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            };
            fetch(url, options).then((response)=>{
                return response.json()}).then((json)=>{setCategories(json);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },[]);
            return (
            <Container>
                <Navigation />
                <Grid container spacing={1}>
                    {this.state.categories.map(category => (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                        <Box bgcolor="primary.main" color="primary.contrastText" p={2}>
                            <span>{category.title}</span>
                        </Box>
                    </Grid>
                ))}               
                </Grid>
            </Container>            
        );
    }

export default Landing;
```

Comment: Ended up going with a solution similar to your second entry, since React hooks can only be utilized with functional classes. Thanks!